# Latex export does not include inlined files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a org file (paper.org) which includes inlined files (abstract.org,intro.org). Like this,

> ** Introduction
> #+INCLUDE: intro.org
> ** Results
> #+INCLUDE: results.org

When I export to a pdf (<kbd>C-c C-e d</kbd>), The subsections in the intro.org do not appear in the generated pdf. Do I need to set a variable? The included files appear when I export to html.

## EDIT

As requested, here is a MWE.

== paper.org ==

> - Abstract
>   #+INCLUDE: "abs.org"
> - Intro
>   #+INCLUDE: "intro.org"

== abs.org ==

> This is the abstract. This should appear.
> ** Abstract Subsection
> This will not.

== intro.org ==

> This is intro. This will appear in the pdf.
> ** Subsection in Intro
> But this will not.

Comment: If you quote the file names (e.g. `#+INCLUDE: "intro.org"`) does it work?

Comment: No. I also tried specifying the type of file ("org"). The text in subsections does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the version of org-mode that I was using. This and another problem were solved when I upgraded. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246350/cannot-export-tables-to-latex-in-org-mode).

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of what you want to do in the manual, at http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html#Include-files.

If that does not work, provide us with a MWE and/or write to the ML -- that could be a bug, then.

Comment: I have added a MWE, please have a look.