# Cannot export tables to latex in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to do the following:

1. I have an `.org` file with the following table:

   ```
   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  
   |---+---+---+---+---|
   | a | b | c | d | e |
   ```
2. I get the following error on pressing <kbd>C-c e d</kbd>, the key binding to export to LaTeX and process the PDF:

   > Symbol's function definition is void: `org-babel-exp-process-buffer`

I am using Org-mode version 7.9.3f on Emacs 24.3.1.

Exporting `.org` files without tables works smoothly.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/shyamupa/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs) to my `.emacs` if anyone needs to have a look.

Comment: You are running an outdated version of `org-mode`. You should try upgrading `org-mode` via `M-x package-install RET org RET` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Strange. I updated the org package as you said, still the org version is 7.9.3f. Is there another host for packages?

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that upgrading `org-mode` from the version built-in to Emacs to a newer version needs to be done "in a session where no `.org` file has been visited, i.e. where no `org` built-in functions have been loaded" (as explained [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html)). Start Emacs via `emacs -Q` and try again.

Comment: I tried that too, did not work. :(

Comment: That's unfortunate, but you'll need to provide some more information about what's going on. What are the exact steps you followed? How did you determine that the installation did not work? Did you get any error messages? Did you restart Emacs without the `-Q` option right after the installation or did you check `org-version` in the same session?

Comment: I ran emacs with -Q flag.

I installed org using package install. It said that 104 files were compiled and 4 skipped. All of the skipped ones had warnings.

I checked the org-version using M-x org-version, in the same session.

Comment: Do you want to take this discussion to chat?

Comment: Sure. But how do I do that? Sorry I have never used chat on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'll open a gallery chat room and send you an invitation.

Comment: Join the room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55860/discussion-of-q24246350). I gave you write access, so you should be able to post messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running an outdated version of `org-mode`. You can upgrade to a newer version by doing

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Note that if you are upgrading from the *built-in* version of `org-mode`, you need to do the installation

> in a session where no `.org` file has been visited, i.e. where no `org` built-in functions have been loaded.

as explained [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html). To ensure that this is the case, start Emacs via `emacs -Q` and *then* install `org` as described above.

---

Taking into account your [current configuration](https://github.com/shyamupa/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs), the next step is to move this

```lisp
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
               '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t))
```

from the bottom to the very top of your `.emacs` file, and comment out all `org`-related customizations for now. By moving the call to `package-initialize` to the top of your `.emacs` file you are making sure all packages installed via the package manager are loaded before your custom configuration is loaded.

When you restart Emacs (without the `-Q` option) and do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-version` <kbd>RET</kbd>, it should now give you something like `8.2.6`, and exporting tables should work fine.

---

As a last step, re-enable your `org`-related customizations one by one by uncommenting them and evaluating them via <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>. If you get any errors, this means the new `org` version introduced some changes that are incompatible with what your code is trying to do. <sub>In that case you might want to ask a separate question.</sub>